# How to specify username and password to get sources in TFS2008?

Tags: tfs, msbuild

TFS2008 getting sources not working due to user permissions

Hi

My new buildserver is not working, is not getting the sources. By default TFSBuild uses windows account to get the sources.. but as in my case buildserver is in a different domain of TFS is not working. I could add permissions and have it fix.
But is not possible at the moment.

So second best solution should be specifying username/password that TFSBuild is going to use CoreGet task... maybe in InitializeBuild, InitializeWorkspace or BeforeGet tasks.. or maybe as a property.

But I don't know if it is possible. So my question is:

**Is possible to specify username and password to get sources in TFS2008? If so, how? Any link where they explain it?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

TFSBuild uses standard Windows authentication techniques to authenticate to Team Foundation Server.  By default, it will authenticate using your domain credentials.  As you note, you could add the appropriate permissions in order to accomplish this, but you can also specify credentials in the Windows Credential Manager: go to Control Panel > User Accounts > Credential Manager and you can add Windows Credentials for your TFS server.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have access to Build Agent server (I am in big company and probably admins will do it in no less that 2 weeks)

How can I add different credentials? (my user name and password would be enough to do it)
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not following - do you have control over the TFS server?  Or are you just trying to specify the username / password inside the build script itself?

Comment: Exactly. I don't have control over TFS server. I can only run builds on it. So the only way is specifiying username/password inside of the build script itself...